# Safe dereferencing a dynamic property in dart

Tags: dart

In dart, we can safe dereference a property like this:

`myObj?.property`

But when I try to do it for a dynamic property like:

`myObj?.['property']`

This gives syntax error.

So is this even possible in dart?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/376#issuecomment-624193530

Comment: If you're asking about safely retrieving a `Map` element where the `Map` might be null, another alternative is to use [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) which provides a `get()` extension on `Map`.  Then you can do `myMap?.get(key)`.  It additionally allows the key to be statically type-checked, unlike the normal `Map.operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that just yet, so you're better to go with

```
if (myObj != null) {
  myObj['property'];
}
```